# Reverse Vowels in a String in C#

Tags: c#, list, linq, nunit, stringbuilder

I am trying to take a string as input and return the string with only the vowels reversed.  It is error free but not bug free.  It is failing on **Test19()** and **Test20**.  Running out of ideas how to fix this or why I am having issues on this test.  All other test pass.  First code block is my code followed by the test I created in the second block.

This is the link to the page that details more information on the test I made.
[Nunit.org StringAssert (NUnit 2.2.3)](https://nunit.org/docs/2.5.9/stringAssert.html)

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Vowels
{
    public class reverseVowels
    {
        public static bool IsVowel(char c)
        {
            char[] vowels = new[] { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U' };
            return vowels.Any(ch => ch == c);
        }

        public static string reverseVowelsOfString(string s)
        {
            List<char> list = (from char c in s
                               where IsVowel(c)
                               select c).ToList();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (char v in s)
            {
                if (IsVowel(v))
                {
                    sb.Append(list.Last());
                    list.Remove(list.Last());
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.Append(v);
                }
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

```
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace Vowels
{
    public class VowelsTest
    {
        [Test]
        public void Test1() => StringAssert.Contains("hollo, werld", reverseVowels.reverseVowelsOfString("hello, world"));

        [Test]
        public void Test2() => StringAssert.Contains("cadisegnol", reverseVowels.reverseVowelsOfString("codesignal"));

        [Test]
        public void Test3() => StringAssert.Contains("UOaIye", reverseVowels.reverseVowelsOfString("eIaOyU"));

        [Test]
        public void Test4() => StringAssert.Contains("", reverseVowels.reverseVowelsOfString(""));

        [Test]
        public void Test5() => StringAssert.Contains(" ", reverseVowels.reverseVowelsOfString(" "));

        [Test]
        public void Test6() => StringAssert.Contains(".a", reverseVowels.reverseVowelsOfString(".a"));

        [Test]
        public void Test7() => StringAssert.Contains("ia", reverseVowels.reverseVowelsOfString("ai"));

        [Test]
        public void Test8() => StringAssert.Contains("Aa", reverseVowels.reverseVowelsOfString("aA"));

        [Test]
        public void Test9() => StringAssert.Contains(".,", reverseVowels.reverseVowelsOfString(".,"));

        [Test]
        public void Test10() => StringAssert.Contains("ab", reverseVowels.reverseVowelsOfString("ab"));

        [Test]
        public void Test11() => StringAssert.Contains("0P", reverseVowels.reverseVowelsOfString("0P"));

        [Test]
        public void Test12() => StringAssert.Contains("!!!", reverseVowels.reverseVowelsOfString("!!!"));

        [Test]
        public void Test13() => StringAssert.Contains("a a", reverseVowels.reverseVowelsOfString("a a"));

        [Test]
        public void Test14() => StringAssert.Contains("abb", reverseVowels.reverseVowelsOfString("abb"));

        [Test]
        public void Test15() => StringAssert.Contains("1b1", reverseVowels.reverseVowelsOfString("1b1"));

        [Test]
        public void Test16() => StringAssert.Contains("abba", reverseVowels.reverseVowelsOfString("abba"));

        [Test]
        public void Test17() => StringAssert.Contains("c#dc", reverseVowels.reverseVowelsOfString("c#dc"));

        [Test]
        public void Test18() => StringAssert.Contains("......a.....", reverseVowels.reverseVowelsOfString("......a....."));

        [Test]
        public void Test19() => StringAssert.Contains("raca e car", reverseVowels.reverseVowelsOfString("race a car"));

        [Test]
        public void Test20() => StringAssert.Contains("SorE was I ere I saw eros.", reverseVowels.reverseVowelsOfString("Sore was I ere I saw Eros."));

        [Test]
        public void Test21() => StringAssert.Contains("a man, a plan, a canal -- PanamA", reverseVowels.reverseVowelsOfString("A man, a plan, a canal -- Panama"));
    }
}
```

```
  X Test19 [43ms]
  Error Message:
     Expected: String containing "raca e car"
  But was:  "raca a cer"

  Stack Trace:
     at Vowels.VowelsTest.Test19() in C:\Users\scott\Desktop\reverseVowelsOfString\test.cs:line 62

  X Test20 [< 1ms]
  Error Message:
     Expected: String containing "SorE was I ere I saw eros."
  But was:  "Soro wEs a arI I sew eres."

  Stack Trace:
     at Vowels.VowelsTest.Test20() in C:\Users\scott\Desktop\reverseVowelsOfString\test.cs:line 65

Test Run Failed.
Total tests: 21
     Passed: 19
     Failed: 2
 Total time: 1.1547 Seconds
```

Comment: It is handy to use [Stack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.stack-1?view=netframework-4.8) in such cases. `Push` adds an element at the end and `Pop` removes the last element and also returns its value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because in test case 19;

```
list = { 'a', 'e', 'a', 'a' }
```

And when you try to remove list.Last() which is 'a', the first element is removed.

```
sb.Append(list.Last()); // appends the last element in the list, which is OK,
list.Remove(list.Last()); // since list.Last() is 'a', removes the first 'a' element in the list.
```

The solution is as simple as:

```
sb.Append(list.Last());
list.RemoveAt(list.Count - 1); // Remove the last item in the list.
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

I would make a few changes. First, I would move the creation of the list of vowels into a one-time allocated class member to avoid unnecessary allocations. I'd also make it a `HashSet<char>` for efficiency reasons:

```
    private static readonly HashSet<char> _vowels = new HashSet<char>(new[] { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U' });
```

Now your `IsVowel()` method can be simplified to just:

```
    public static bool IsVowel(char c) => _vowels.Contains(c);
```

For the method doing all the work, I'd give the variables more meaningful names. `vowels` instead of `list` and `c` instead of `v` since we know it's a char, but not necessarily a vowel (I'm assuming that's what `v` stood for).

I'd also put the list of vowels in a `Stack<char>` so you can easily pop them off as needed.

```
    public static string reverseVowelsOfString(string s)
    {
        Stack<char> vowels = new Stack<char>(s.Where(IsVowel));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (char c in s)
        {
            if (IsVowel(c))
            {
                sb.Append(vowels.Pop());
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append(c);
            }
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: As a note, you can just `return s.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, c) => sb.Append(IsVowel(c) ? vowels.Pop() : c)).ToString();`. Since this code allows it.